# How to Set the properties of typescript object in angular2?

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript class defined as :

```
export class Atom {

  public text:String;
  public image:boolean;
  public equation:boolean;

}
```

I want to make an object of type Atom class and set the properties of object. For this what i am doing is

```
atom:Atom=new Atom();
  atom.text="hello";
```

Error: Subsequent variable declarations must have same type. Variable atom must be of type Atom, but here it is of type any.

Answer (score 1):

```
atom:Atom=new Atom();
atom.image="hello";
```

produces an error because you assign a string, `image` is declared as `boolean` though

You can also use a constructor

```
export class Atom {
  constructor(
    public text?:String,
    public image?:boolean,
    public equation?:boolean) {}
}
```

and then instantiate it with

```
new Atom('someText', true, false);
```

or

```
new Atom({text: 'someText'});
```

Comment: How can i set the particular variable like text.

Comment: can i do : atom=new Atom('someText', true, false);

Comment: and then atom.text="Nitish";

Comment: Yes you can. I updated my answer to make the constructor parameters optional, then you can use the last code line to pass only these you actually want to set when you create the instance. `atom.text = "Nitish"` works always